# detect rows with different ID's but duplicate values pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which collects readings from device. Sometimes there are multiple readings for same sample, and thats stored as seperate ID in my dataframe. Is there a way for me to detect the duplicated ID's by using the columns that have same value?

Sample dataframe:

```
test_df = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'Age': [18,18,19,19,20,21], 'Sex':['Male','Male','Female','Female','Male','Female'], 'Values':[1200,200, 300, 400, 500,600]}
```

I want the result to return ID's `1,2,3,4` since they are duplicated when we compare `Age` and `Sex` column values.

Expected Output:

```
ID    Age     Sex     Values
1     18      Male     1200
2     18      Male     200
3     19      Female   300
4     19      Female   400
```

Comment: provide a sample of what you want the output DataFrame to look like

Comment: Use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `subset` and `keep=False` params: `test_df[test_df.duplicated(subset=['Age', 'Sex'], keep=False)]`

Comment: I know this is off topic, can I get a count of actual ID's in my dataframe? Like in this case My count of actual samples in test_df would be 4 where `ID: 1,3,5,6` , since they are different.

Comment: You can try len(test_df['ID']) to get the count